# Set the pixel format AND create texture from surface in SDL

Tags: c++, pixel, sdl-2, surface, pixelformat

I am currently trying some things using pixel manipulation and I would like to set the pixel format of a SDL_Surface. The problem here is that I am loading up an image with the SDL_image.h. So I have to create a texture from a surface like this:

```
surface = IMG_Load(filePath);
texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface);
```

So I can't use the following function, which I would like to, or can I?:

```
texture = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ARGB8888, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STATIC, 640, 480);
```

The thing is, that I want to set the SDL_PixelFormat to be able to mess around with the pixels. How can I both do this and create the texture based on a surface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SDL2 API provides the function `SDL_ConvertSurface`:

```
SDL_Surface* SDL_ConvertSurface(SDL_Surface*           src,
                                const SDL_PixelFormat* fmt,
                                Uint32                 flags)
```

You should be able to do

```
surface = IMG_Load(filePath);
// Call SDL_ConvertSurface to set the pixel format of the surface you have created.
texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface);
```

Reference: https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_ConvertSurface